# Azure CLI SQL DB Restore time format

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-cli

I am writing a Powershell script using Azure CLI for doing an Azure SQL Instance restore.  This is my script so far:

```
az login

$AzureSubscription = "SubscriptionName"
az account set --subscription $AzureSubscription

$RGName = "ResourceGroupName"
$SrvName = "AzureSQLServerName"

$RestoreDateTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddHours(-1).ToString()
$RestoreDateTimeString = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddHours(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm")
$RestoreName = $SrvName + "_" + $RestoreDateTimeString

az sql db restore --dest-name $RestoreName --resource-group $RGName --server $SrvName --name $SrvName  --time = $RestoreDateTime
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
az: error: unrecognized arguments: 7/10/2019 10:39:21 AM
usage: az [-h] [--verbose] [--debug]
          [--output {json,jsonc,table,tsv,yaml,none}] [--query JMESPATH]
          {sql} ...
```

I have tried a variety of date-time formats, but, I can't seem to get any of them to work.  Is there a specific format that is needed?  Should I be passing a different value into time?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the `--time` parameter wants the datetime formatted as 'Sortable date/time pattern' (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss).

This should do it:

```
$RestoreDateTime       = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddHours(-1)
$RestoreDateTimeString = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm}' -f $RestoreDateTime
$RestoreName           = '{0}_{1}' -f  $SrvName, $RestoreDateTimeString

# format the datetime as Sortable date/time pattern 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'
# see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings
$azRestoreTime         = '{0:s}' -f $RestoreDateTime

az sql db restore --dest-name $RestoreName --resource-group $RGName --server $SrvName --name $SrvName  --time $azRestoreTime
```

Hope that helps

Comment: That appears to have solved my problem.  Thank you.

Comment: I think the ISO8601 [Round-trip ("O", "o") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier) should also work.